# Fully dynamic ActiveReport report creation

Tags: activereports

I would like to use ActiveReports to generate reports on the-fly, using a data set determined by the user and some properties, such as bold header, etc. Does anyone know of a good walk-through or can provide me with a code sample that is a point? All the posts I've found give dead links that drop you right at the componentsource home page. I am looking for a jumping off point in either VB .NET or C#, but the end result is a web project that will feed into the ActiveReports HTML5 viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good resource, of course, after posing the question here. In case anyone else has trouble finding it, I found this: http://help.gcactivereports.com/2013/06/28/creating-activereports-on-the-fly/

Answer (score 0):

Does that link help?  That is for section reports.

For Page and RDL reports, there is a sample that comes with the installer.  If you go under My Documents on your machine, the componentone samples folder has a CreateReport sample that does it.  See layoutbuilder.cs file in that folder.

-->ActiveReports 9\Page Reports And RDL Reports\API\CreateReport\C#\CreateReport